# error : Expected expression before '{' toke while defining a 2 dimensional array in a switch statement in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

To go staright forward : i have to do a project in C, but i get an error with my partner and we cannot figure it out how to fix it. It tells us that there is an error with an expected expression before '{' in each case of the switch_statement when we define the 1's and 0's. Does anyone have an idea ?

```
int **create_block_sh(int height, int width, int desired_shape)
{
   int **block = create_2D_dyn(height, width);
   switch (desired_shape)
   {
    case 1 :
        block[height][width] = {{1,0,0},
                                {1,1,0},
                                {1,1,1}};
        break;
    case 2:
        block[height][width] = {{1,0,0},
                                {1,0,0},
                                {1,1,1}};
        break;
    case 3:
        block[height][width] = {{1,0,0},
                                {1,0,0},
                                {1,0,0}};
        break;

    default:
        printf("error !!");
        break;
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot : [Screenshot of CodeBlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3ti.png)

Thanks everyone, but with some furthermore helps I found an alternative, which is  : block = (int *[]){(int []){0,1,1}, (int []){1,1,1}, (int []){1,1,0}};
Here is a screenshot : [http://prntscr.com/rlco7f]

Comment: What's the type of `block[height][width]`?  Whan you can answer this question you know what's wrong

Comment: Also you forgot `return block;` at the end of the `create_block_sh` function, but that's another story

Comment: The relevant error there is `invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is wrong:

```
block[height][width] = {{1,0,0},
                        {1,1,0},
                        {1,1,1}};
```

`block` is a 2D array of integers, each element is just an integer. So its wrong to assign like that.

All you can do is this:

```
block[height][width] = 1;
```

Also, doing this is wrong:
    block[height] = {1,2,3}

You can do what you have only while declaring an array, example:

```
int arr[3][3] = {{1,0,0},
                 {1,1,0},
                 {1,1,1}};
```

Also, please put your the expressions for each `case` statements inside curly braces as such:

```
switch(...){
    case 1:
    {
      // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. With some other help I've found that the following code works : 
            block = (int *[]){(int []){0,1,1},
                              (int []){1,1,1},
                              (int []){1,1,0}};

Comment: I see. While that might work, its extremely hard to read syntactically. I would refactoring your code a bit and avoid using such hard to read syntax unless absolutely necessary :)